# How do I set up the Master Key in my iOS Swift app to connect to Parse Server?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I can connect to my Parse Server using the URL, appId, and clientKey in my iOS app

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // ...Configure Parse server...
    let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "APP_ID"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "CLIENT_KEY"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "http://my_server.com:1337/parse"
    })
    Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(parseConfiguration)

    return true
}
```

***But I want to start developing with Push Notifications***, so I need to include my server Master Key.

**How do I incorporate the Master Key into my AppDelegate.swift to connect to the server?**

I tried to see if there was a method to call for masterKey like there is for clientKey as mention in above code lines, but no such method exists

Comment: Follow the instructions at this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/128313/parse-server-tutorial). The masterKey is only need to send them out via the server side.  In your AppDelegate you need to make sure to register for notifications. Also paste actual code when ever possible instead of an image.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice on the image. And thanks for the link!

Comment: Did the information I provide help? Or do still have questions?

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything on the link pertaining to incorporating masterKey. And through some more research, I figure it's not possible to integrate the masterKey in-app. So, I'm exploring other methods. Right now, I am experimenting with sending pushes from the dashboard and receiving them with my app